# HTML5 pattern for phone number with parentheses

Tags: regex, html

I've got an HTML5 pattern that works great for phone numbers in the following format:

```
111-222-3333
111 222 3333
(777)-888-9999
(777)888-9999
```

But if a user enters

```
(777-999-9999
```

It passes the validation. Ideally I'd want this to throw an error since the parentheses is clearly not closed. Here is my pattern:

```
pattern="^\(?\d{3}\)?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$"
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I've been banging my head against a wall for hours on this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The optionalities of the two parenthesis are independent of each other. Use an alternation:

```
pattern="(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}"
```

Comment: This worked perfect! Thanks @Bergi. One thing I'm confused about is why the need for a ":" am I missing something here or is that really necessary?

Comment: The `?:` modifier will make the [group non-capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Not really necessary, though.

Comment: The `^` and `$` characters at the beginning and end are also useless in the case of an HTML 5 input pattern, as they are implied.

Comment: What if you wanted this to also pick up (777) 888-9999 where there is a space between the parenthesis and the next set of numbers? So all 5 of these work.

Comment: @Xander: there already is an optional space after the parenthesis in the answer